# What makes an airport luggage scanner different from an X-ray scanner used in a hospital

Tags: bones, broken-bones, x-rays

Once upon a time I had an great idea.

Instead of checking if my bones were broken or not for a price. I would make it totally free by putting my arms in a scanner used in a building and show the photos to an doctor friend thus make the X ray check free.

But I have heard medical ones are lot more accurate and ones used in the airports aren't high resolution enough for an medical examination.

It's been years since my teenage self thought about it and I am here.

According to some simple research. [An X-Ray ay scan for arm and fingers take 0.001 mSv](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.radiologyinfo.org/en/pdf/safety-xray.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjZzaKEx-LfAhVRqIsKHevlAkgQFjABegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw36nnO48ctxKBYgivfCNxeh) while [an luggage scanner gives 0.04 mSv](https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/hhe/reports/pdfs/2003-0206-3067.pdf).

I don't have much information whetever the scanners used in the airports are different from the ones used in a hospital thus that's all the information I know.

Comment: And what has your research found so far?

Comment: let's ignore for the moment that most scanners are staffed by people who would be fired if they let someone put their body in, and just ask "the photos? what photos?" Scanners in buildings etc show a live pic on a screen. Are you thinking maybe you'll just snap a phone pic of that? Seriously?

Comment: @CareyGregory x ray body scanners used in the airports are 30 times less powerful than the X ray we get in a Norma day.

Comment: @CareyGregory carry on baggage scanners are less than the average daily x ray dose we get too but the checked baggage scanners are lot more powerful. Around 100 times more powerful.

Comment: @CareyGregory https://hps.org/publicinformation/ate/q11881.html gggg

Comment: @CareyGregory http://hps.org/publicinformation/ate/q12361.html hggggggggg https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/hhe/reports/pdfs/2003-0206-3067.pdf gggg also sorry for the broken touchscreen which made me multi comment

Comment: @KateGregory back in the day when my grandpa was still the commissioner of the police for the İzmir. I watched some TV shows about corruption where high ranking government workers could order anything and get it done and that's what my early teen mind thought. I still remember how my childhood book was a about security and guns but the idea came from an private security book about x ray scanners.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood my question as being conversational. What I was asking you to do was show in your question what research you've done. That's a requirement here. And Kate is right that your question is borderline ridiculous. This site isn't the place to post questions you imagined in your teens. Do you have a serious question? If so, please edit it to include the research you've done and make it a real question and not just a teen fantasy.

Comment: @CareyGregory just a comment before I edit it which may take hours later. I will try to find how much radiation is needed but research may take some time too

Comment: Interestingly you're not the [first person to think of this](https://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/formula1/45239949)

Comment: @motosubatsu I guess the words "detailed scan" is enough for an answer. Who could know someone silent like me and a F1 clown wanted to do the same thing anyway. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @JonathanIrons unfortunately the article only indicates what Kimi was trying to do - no real detail on how *effective* the results were. Fun anecdote though!

Comment: As you have researched, the luggage scanner spreads 40 times much more radiation then medical x-ray. So, I want to ask you something: Why would you take high dose radiation unnecessarily?(0,04 mSv) Seriously, what is you purpose which for the sake of your health?

Comment: @ÇAGATAY: This is an educated guess and hence not an answer, but: As far as I know, intensity correlates to the greyscale in X-Rad Imaging. If the intensity is in fact amped up 40 times, it would mean everything becomes 40 times darker. The main reason why X-Ray imaging is so effective is due to the greyscale. You‘d totally scree that because everything would be almost black and unintelligible to human eyes.

Comment: @ÇAĞATAYKAYA because why not?

Comment: @Narusan this should be an answer. Ifn only someone That knew about x ray came here